# Cannot register user on my website (PHP, Unity3D)

Tags: c#, php, mysql, unity-game-engine

I have a website and I want to use it as a place where I can store data (like username, password etc.) for my multiplayer game that I'm making in Unity3D.

Now I want to register someone (add the username and password to the MySQL database) using C# and Unity3D. I use the WWW class to communicate to the website. In my point of view the code I made in Unity3D is working fine, but when I visit phpMyAdmin and search for the new registered user, I can't find it. So I figured, the problem must be in the PHP script, but I can't find it.

Once again the problem is that the username and the password are not added to the MySQL table.

I'll post both scripts, although I think the script in Unity3D is working OK. Please note that I'm PHP absolute beginner.

```
<?php

$mysql_host = "example.host.com";
$mysql_database = "example_database";
$mysql_user = "exampleuser";
$mysql_password = "toomanysecrets";

try
{

$toQuery = 'SELECT name,
                password
            FROM basicUserInfo
            ORDER BY name';

if ($_POST["name"] || $_POST["password"])
{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_host;dbname=$mysql_database", $mysql_user,     $mysql_password);
    echo "Connected to $mysql_database at $mysql_host successfully!";
    $forQuery = 'INSERT INTO  `a1936371_userinf`.`basicUserInfo` (
                `name` ,`password`
                )
                VALUES (
                    \'$_POST[\'name\']\',  \'$_POST[\'password\']\'
                    )';

        if (!$conn->query($forQuery))
        {
            echo "Failed to add data!";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Added data sucessfully";
        }
    //Close the connection
    $conn = null;
}

} catch (PDOException $pe)
{
   die("Could not connect to the database $mysql_database:" . $pe->getMessage());
}
```

Unity3D:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
    {
        Register("testt", "test1");
    }
}

public void Register(string playername, string password)
{
    StartCoroutine(RegisterOnServer(playername, password));
}

IEnumerator RegisterOnServer(string playerName, string password)
{
    string url = "http://deathrunserv.net16.net/index.php";

    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("name", playerName);
    form.AddField("password", password);

    WWW www = new WWW(url);
    yield return www;
    Debug.Log("Done!");

}
```

Comment: Please remove your database credentials from this post and immediately change them!

Comment: Upps, I totally forgot about that. Thank you very much vaxquis and @tillz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your C# code, you're not using WWWForm anywhere. Try:

```
WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
form.AddField("name", playerName);
form.AddField("password", password);

WWW www = new WWW(url, form);
yield return www;
Debug.Log("Done!");
```

Comment: Oh, that's what the problem was! Thank you very much!